# How to Windows clients use the correct IP to connect to the remote systems with multiple IPs

Tags: windows, dns

My question is more theoretical..

If a target server that I need to connect to over RPC/WMI/WSMAN has multiple IP addresses how does the Window client get hold of the correct IP? Does the client go through iteratively until one of them responds?

As I understand, a server can have multiple IP addresses for replication, heart beat, client connections, management , backup etc. and all except management/client may not be reachable hence I wanted to know how do clients find the correct IP from DNS when the DNS can return  multiple IPs as a response to the client lookup query. Thanks.

Comment: Addressing like that is part of the TCP/IP packet.  The target IP and port is contained in the packet. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do clients find the correct IP from DNS

They assume that *all* IP addresses returned by the query are correct.

Yes, if the first address doesn't respond in time, the client will try the second one, then third, etc. (in undefined order – DNS records are unordered), but this can get noticeably slow, and the only time it should happen is during some kind of network/configuration issue, not during normal operation.

If some addresses are deliberately not reachable, **they shouldn't be in DNS.** The server's main DNS entry should represent the main entry point – it could still return multiple addresses, of course (such as IPv4 + IPv6 for a start), but all of them should behave exactly the same. Things like "management" addresses should have a different DNS entry (if they go in DNS at all).

When you're relying on automatic DNS updates through Active Directory, you can disable registration for unwanted network adapters (Ethernet ports). If it's a client or a member server (not a DC), disable "Register this connection's addresses in DNS" in the adapter's *Properties* dialog. (If the server is an AD DC, there are [different steps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/unwanted-nic-registered-dns-mulithomed-dc).)

Comment: thank you. That's clear to me now.

Answer (score 0):

DNS SRV records are one way.   The SRV record is heavily used by Active Directory, SIP, and any other protocols to not only find the hosts offering a service but also the IP and port to connect to.